# Passing JSON from PHP to JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
$testArray = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");
$myTest = json_encode($testArray);
$javascript = "
                <script>
                const displayExternalUrl = JSON.parse($myTest);
                console.log(displayExternalUrl);
                 </script>
                 ";
echo $javascript;
```

I try to pass $myTest (which is PHP) to const displayExternalUrl (which is Javascript), the Log says

`caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'J', "John,Mary,"... is not valid JSON     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Where is the wrong Code?

Comment: `$myTest` is already valid JavaScript source. Remove the `JSON.parse` call. Simply look at the generated source code in the browser. [`JSON.parse`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a _string_. The code, however, will include `JSON.parse(["John","Mary","Peter","Sally"]);`. The argument will be stringified to `"John,Mary,Peter,Sally"`, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: `json_encode($testArray)` converts the PHP array `$testArray` to valid JavaScript JSON. `JSON.parse($myTest)` is telling JavaScript to convert the already valid JSON again. Simply change `JSON.parse($myTest)` to `$myTest`

Answer (score 0):

This code is correctly using json_encode() to convert a PHP array into a JSON string and then passing it to JavaScript. This approach is generally safe and minimizes the risk of XSS attacks.

```
$testArray = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");
$myTest = json_encode($testArray);
$javascript = "
                <script>
                const displayExternalUrl = " . $myTest . ";
                console.log(displayExternalUrl);
                 </script>
                 ";
echo $javascript;
```